# Do I really burn more calories in biking than hiking?

Tags: calories, bicycling, app

I use AllTrails app with Apple Watch to monitor my tracks and I am surprised that my biking burns more calories than my hiking. But I feel like hiking is more strenuous and handwork.

Here are my comparing activities:

Hiking | 11 miles | 3000 ft elevation gain | 4:40 time | 2342 calories.
Biking | 60 miles | 1300 ft elevation gain | 5:40 time | 3540 calories

The biking trip was an hour longer but it does comparatively burn more calories and I see this pattern consistently in my biking vs hiking trips.

I do find biking easier but is that really the case it burns more calories given my case? Can I trust my apps on these? :) And how would you explain it!

Comment: Seems about right - https://www.nutristrategy.com/caloriesburned.htm.